# Detecting orientation of iPhone using C++

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder-10.3-rio

Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3.2 Enterprise

Searching the internet, I could not find any FMX code for this. Based on Delphi code, this should have worked but the compiler does not like it

```
if (Application->FormFactor->Orientations == Fmx::Types::TScreenOrientations::Landscape) {
    //Landscape
}
```

Also, the value of Application->FormFactor->Orientations is the same whatever the orientation of the iphone. {System::SetBase = {Data = {[0] = 11 '\v'}}}
How does one determine the orientation?

Answer (score 1):

The `Orientations` property is a [`TFormOrientations`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TFormOrientations), which is a [`System::Set`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Set) of [`TFormOrientation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TFormOrientation) values.  You can't use [`Set::operator==`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Set.operator_H3DH3D) to compare it to a single value, which is why you are getting a compiler error. However, you can use the [`Set::Contains()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Set.Contains) method to check if it has a given value, eg:

```cpp
if (Application->FormFactor->Orientations.Contains(Fmx::Forms::TFormOrientation::Landscape)) {
    //...
}
```

In any case, the `Orientations` property specifies which orientation(s) the application's Forms are *allowed* to take (a value of 11 has its 1st, 2nd, and 4th bits set to 1, which correspond to the `Portrait`, `Landscape`, and `InvertedLandscape` orientations being enabled).  It does not report what the device's *current* orientation is.  For that, use the [`IFMXScreenService::GetScreenOrientation()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXScreenService.GetScreenOrientation) method instead, eg:

```cpp
_di_IFMXScreenService ScreenService;
if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService), &ScreenService)) {
    if (ScreenService->GetScreenOrientation() == Fmx::Types::TScreenOrientation::Landscape) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Remy, I know you are right.  But I’m curious if you see any real problems with my approach using Screen dimension check.  Thanks

Comment: @relayman357 checking the screen dimensions only tells you whether the device is long ways up/down or long ways left/right, but it doesn't differentiate between normal landscape (screen top is to the left) and inverse landscape (screen top is to the right), or normal portrait (screen top is up) and inverse portrait (screen top is down). Orientation is relative to a fixed point on the device (such as a vendor logo, a specific corner, etc) and reflects where that point is located relative to the rest of the device in physical space